# Nodejs Passportjs logging in as different users from the same browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to test features in my website that is different based on the user. I tried logging in from 2 separate tab but it each time I sign out and login from a different tab the older tab gets signed out and logged in as the new user as well. I thought that the cookies that are stored in the browser are tab specific. Each new tab has new cookies but I was wrong.

Does browser store one single cookie for the URLs that are the same?

I know facebook and other services works the same way but I always thought that this was possible using some extra programming that facebook wrote to insure security

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617536/store-browser-tab-specific-data Hope this helps

Comment: It does. Thank you